# How to write dynamic SQL using values from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a table that actually holds the table name and column name of another table like this:

TestTable

```
TheTable nvarchar
TheColumn nvarchar
```

Sudo Logic

```
SELECT
     t.Something
    ,t.SomethingElse
    ,t.TheTable
    ,t.TheColumn
    ,(SELECT *TheColumn* FROM *TheTable*) AS Something
FROM TestTable t
```

Even writing this question I'm getting several suggestions of similar questions, but I'm hoping for a much simpler example if there is one, so no intention to duplicate a question. Other examples seem specific and are quite extensive.

Thank you.

Comment: So, what happens if `TheTable` has more than one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some dynamic sql loosely based on your sample code:

```
/* set up a few parameters */
DECLARE @table_name AS nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @column_name AS nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(1000)

/* set the parameter values */
SELECT @table_name=TheTable, @column_name=TheColumn 
FROM TestTable
WHERE -- ADD SOME LOGIC HERE TO GET SINGLE ROW

/* Build SQL String with parameters */
SET @SQLQuery = 
'SELECT ' + @column_name + 
' FROM ' +  @table_name 
-- + ' WHERE clause if required'

/* Execute SQL */
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using dynamic sql.  Below are a couple of links to get you started:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

You should also be aware of the [potential dangers](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) of using Dynamic sql.